# Dimensional analysis on $v=kF^xl^ym^t$

Tags: dimensional-analysis

The velocity V of a wave moving in a stretched string can be written as, ( $v=kF^xl^ym^t$ ). where $F$ is the tension in the string, $l$ is it's length and m is the mass of the string and $k$ is a dimensionless constant. DETERMINE THE VALUES OF $x, y, t$.

Comment: $x=\frac{1}{2}$ ,$y=\frac{1}{2}$ and $t=-\frac{1}{2}$ works straightaway.

Comment: @HVxvejjw Please write it clearly